# Emulating Zend Framework's CookieJar

Tags: php, zend-framework, cookies, curl

I'm porting over some function using Zend_Http_CookieJar but need some clarification. Presumably the CookieJar only lasts as long as the instance is running. So could I use curl to produce the same thing? :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookiefile");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookiefile");
```

So my real question is whether if there were three instances of the script running would their use of the cookiefile clash?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know from own experience, but I think yes, this could lead to conflicts.

It's probably safest to create a unique cookie jar per process, e.g. using [`tempnam()`](http://www.php.net/tempnam).

Comment: I thought so, I know the period it uses it is very short but its definately better to be safe than sorry!